# Limit the number of results returned by Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search

I am having an issue where i want to reduce the number of results from Elastic search to 1,000 no matter how many matching results are there matching, but this should not affect the ranking and scoring.

I was trying `terminate_after`, but that seems to just tell the elastic search to just get the top N results without considering the scores. Correct me if am wrong.

Any help on this?

**EDIT:**

I am already using pagination. So, using Size in [From/Size](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/search-request-from-size.html#search-request-from-size) will only affect the size of current page. But i want to limit the size of total results to 1,000 and then pagination on that.

Answer (score 54):

How about using [From/Size](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/search-request-from-size.html#search-request-from-size) in order to return the requirement number of results:

```
GET /_search
{
    "from" : 0, "size" : 1000,
    "query" : {
        //your query
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check the **EDIT** in the question.

Answer (score 25):

You can just specify the size as an parameter.

```
GET /_search?size=1000
{
    "query" : {
        //your query
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

I know this question aged a little since it was asked, but i stumbled over this and i am surprised no one could give the correct answer.

Elasticsearch indices have an [index module](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules.html) called `max_result_window`. You can find it [in the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules.html#dynamic-index-settings) under *dynamic index settings*.

> **`index.max_result_window`**
>    The maximum value of `from` + `size` for searches to this index. Defaults to `10000`. Search requests take heap memory and time proportional to `from` + `size` and this limits that memory. See *Scroll* or *Search After* for a more efficient alternative to raising this.

So basically instead of limiting `from` or `size` (or a combination of those), you set `max_result_window` to `1000` and ES will only return a maximum of 1000 hits per request.

If you are using an index definition in a separate JSON file to create your index, you can set this value there under `yourindexname.settings.index.max_result_window`.

I hope this helps the folks still looking for a solution to this problem!

Comment: Importantly, all your queries will stop counting results after it they hit max_result_window (even if you're only returning the top 10 results), therefore lowering can be an effective way to reduce response times, particularly for queries with a lot of matches.

Comment: I dont think you're 100% right, max_result_window is not for that purpose. Per his question, he doesn't want to do internal pagination which can be done using `from` and `size` based query. But, what s/he want is, to have external pagination, which can be done using `scroll` based queries, with a page size of 100/1000 requests. even then it will be having limitation of 10k, if total result spans across that; so if we want more data, we might want to alter that setting, to increase the limit value. In short, that setting `max_result_window` should not be used for pagination purpose.

Comment: @HariKishore I didn't say they should use `max_results_window` for pagination. They want to limit the results independently from any pagination approaches. That's what this is for.

Answer (score -3):

did you try with

```
terminate_after
```

The maximum number of documents to collect for each shard, upon reaching which the query execution will terminate early. If set, the response will have a boolean field terminated_early to indicate whether the query execution has actually terminated_early. Defaults to no terminate_after.

Comment: yes, as i have mentioned in the question, i have already tried `terminate_after`.

Comment: @RohitWagh i also tryed this but its messed up the sorting. My solution was to sort the result base on creation date and limit last 60 days.